# XSLT grouping: first 10 elements as group and next 10 elements as second different group name

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I am trying to group the element1 tags with (key and price) based on position, I can receive the element1 like 30 or 40 in multiples of 10. but I am facing issue while grouping them like first 10 will be an element 1 and second group should name as element2 and so on

I am not able to group them correctly and failing to rename the groups.

**XSLT** :

```
    <xsl:for-each select="element1">
    <xsl:element name="element{position()}">
    <xsl:element name="key"><xsl:value-of select="key"/></xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="price"><xsl:value-of select="price"/></xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>

    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

**Input :**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pricingCondition>
 <element1>
  <key>TAX</key>
  <price>0</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>TAX1</key>
  <price>2</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>RATE</key>
  <price>7</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>PRICE</key>
  <price>24</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>FREIGHTVALUE</key>
  <price>0</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>NET</key>
  <price>25</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>TAX2</key>
  <price>1</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>TAX3</key>
  <price>30</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>GROSSP</key>
  <price>267</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>GROSSV</key>
  <price>4300</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>TAX</key>
  <price>01</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>TAX1</key>
  <price>02</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>RATE</key>
  <price>73</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>PRICE</key>
  <price>247</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>FREIGHTVALUE</key>
  <price>0</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>NET</key>
  <price>15</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>TAX2</key>
  <price>11</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>TAX3</key>
  <price>10</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>GROSSP</key>
  <price>167</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>GROSSV</key>
  <price>2300</price>
 </element1>
</pricingCondition>
```

**OutPut**:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pricingCondition>
 <element1>
  <key>TAX</key>
  <price>0</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>TAX1</key>
  <price>2</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>RATE</key>
  <price>7</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>PRICE</key>
  <price>24</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>FREIGHTVALUE</key>
  <price>0</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>NET</key>
  <price>25</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>TAX2</key>
  <price>1</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>TAX3</key>
  <price>30</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>GROSSP</key>
  <price>267</price>
 </element1>
 <element1>
  <key>GROSSV</key>
  <price>4300</price>
 </element1>
 <element2>
  <key>TAX</key>
  <price>01</price>
 </element2>
 <element2>
  <key>TAX1</key>
  <price>02</price>
 </element2>
 <element2>
  <key>RATE</key>
  <price>73</price>
 </element2>
 <element2>
  <key>PRICE</key>
  <price>247</price>
 </element2>
 <element2>
  <key>FREIGHTVALUE</key>
  <price>0</price>
 </element2>
 <element2>
  <key>NET</key>
  <price>15</price>
 </element2>
 <element2>
  <key>TAX2</key>
  <price>11</price>
 </element2>
 <element2>
  <key>TAX3</key>
  <price>10</price>
 </element2>
 <element2>
  <key>GROSSP</key>
  <price>167</price>
 </element2>
 <element2>
  <key>GROSSV</key>
  <price>2300</price>
 </element2>
</pricingCondition>
```

Comment: Post Input xml too.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/pricingCondition">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="element1">
            <xsl:element name="element{ceiling(position() div 10)}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Nope, I want to group elements internally by changing the name of the element1 for every 10 positions. first 10 will be element1 and second 10 will be element2 like this..

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what this does.